# Android Intent not working

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, android-manifest

I am trying to start an activity with using an intent but it never seems to work. I've tried scoping the variables all over the place and it never seems to work. I am using a thread to start the activity. If it is because of the IDE, I am using android studio. I'm just wondering what the mistake ids here because I can't find any. I have included the Android manifest because I might have messed up there too. Here is the code:

```
package com.mtprogramming.magicsquaresgame;

import com.mtprogramming.magicsquaresgame.util.SystemUiHider;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

/**
 * An example full-screen activity that shows and hides the system UI (i.e.
 * status bar and navigation/system bar) with user interaction.
 *
 * @see SystemUiHider
 */
public class Opening extends Activity {
/**
 * Whether or not the system UI should be auto-hidden after
 * {@link #AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS} milliseconds.
 */
private static final boolean AUTO_HIDE = true;


/**
 * If {@link #AUTO_HIDE} is set, the number of milliseconds to wait after
 * user interaction before hiding the system UI.
 */
private static final int AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS = 3000;

/**
 * If set, will toggle the system UI visibility upon interaction. Otherwise,
 * will show the system UI visibility upon interaction.
 */
private static final boolean TOGGLE_ON_CLICK = true;

/**
 * The flags to pass to {@link SystemUiHider#getInstance}.
 */
private static final int HIDER_FLAGS = SystemUiHider.FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;

/**
 * The instance of the {@link SystemUiHider} for this activity.
 */
private SystemUiHider mSystemUiHider;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_opening);
Thread timer = new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        try{
            sleep(5000);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            Intent open = new Intent(Opening.this,Menu.class);
            startActivity(open);
        }
    }
};
    timer.start();
    final View controlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
    final View contentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);

    // Set up an instance of SystemUiHider to control the system UI for
    // this activity.
    mSystemUiHider = SystemUiHider.getInstance(this, contentView, HIDER_FLAGS);
    mSystemUiHider.setup();
    mSystemUiHider
            .setOnVisibilityChangeListener(new SystemUiHider.OnVisibilityChangeListener() {
                // Cached values.
                int mControlsHeight;
                int mShortAnimTime;

                @Override
                @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
                public void onVisibilityChange(boolean visible) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
                        // If the ViewPropertyAnimator API is available
                        // (Honeycomb MR2 and later), use it to animate the
                        // in-layout UI controls at the bottom of the
                        // screen.
                        if (mControlsHeight == 0) {
                            mControlsHeight = controlsView.getHeight();
                        }
                        if (mShortAnimTime == 0) {
                            mShortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(
                                    android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);
                        }
                        controlsView.animate()
                                .translationY(visible ? 0 : mControlsHeight)
                                .setDuration(mShortAnimTime);
                    } else {
                        // If the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs aren't
                        // available, simply show or hide the in-layout UI
                        // controls.
                        controlsView.setVisibility(visible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
                    }

                    if (visible && AUTO_HIDE) {
                        // Schedule a hide().
                        delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
                    }
                }
            });

    // Set up the user interaction to manually show or hide the system UI.
    contentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (TOGGLE_ON_CLICK) {
                mSystemUiHider.toggle();
            } else {
                mSystemUiHider.show();
            }
        }
    });

    // Upon interacting with UI controls, delay any scheduled hide()
    // operations to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
    // while interacting with the UI.

}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Trigger the initial hide() shortly after the activity has been
    // created, to briefly hint to the user that UI controls
    // are available.
    delayedHide(100);
}


/**
 * Touch listener to use for in-layout UI controls to delay hiding the
 * system UI. This is to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
 * while interacting with activity UI.
 */
View.OnTouchListener mDelayHideTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (AUTO_HIDE) {
            delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
        }
        return false;
    }
};

Handler mHideHandler = new Handler();
Runnable mHideRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mSystemUiHider.hide();
    }
};

/**
 * Schedules a call to hide() in [delay] milliseconds, canceling any
 * previously scheduled calls.
 */
private void delayedHide(int delayMillis) {
    mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHideRunnable);
    mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHideRunnable, delayMillis);
}}
```

And the Android Manifest:

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.mtprogramming.magicsquaresgame.Opening"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
            android:name="com.mtprogramming.magicsquaresgame.Menu"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            >
        <intent-filter> <action> android:name="com.mtprogramming.magicsquaresgame.MENU"</action>

            </intent-filter>


    </activity>
</application>
```

The target API is 16-17 by the way.

Comment: this is not good way. just show where you are getting problem

Comment: pls post your error logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove these following lines from finally block
 `Intent open = new Intent(Opening.this,Menu.class);
            startActivity(open);`

and put these lines in somewhere outside thread. You can open an activity on UI thread only not in Background.

Answer (score 0):

Dude,you cant start activity inside a thread. you need to start your activty from UI thread.

I would recommend using a handler. Im not familier with the looper class but i just simply passed a Handler object when creating threads from the uiThread. then sent messages to the handler from the thread and doing the appropriate ui stuff by overwriting the handlemessage in the handler. So my suggestion would be to use an anonymous innner class for the handler (in the ui thread) and then pass that to the runnable class.

Answer (score 0):

get rid of that Thread stuff, if you just want to start an activity after some delay just use View.postDelayed(runnable, delay) method

Comment: Can I have some documentation for this new thing? Which Runnable do I use?

Comment: you should use a new Runnable where in run method you call startActivity